# iBeacon region exit when taking call with bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon, ios10, region-monitoring

We are using `iBeacons` to tag when you are driving your vehicle. But lately we have had a large number of of our users reporting that the `iBeacons` are not found when they are also using their phone for streaming music or answering calls over `Bluetooth` in their vehicles. But it only happens with **some Bluetooth connections**.

Are there any new settings in **iOS 10** that we need to be aware of?

Are there anyone else experiencing these kind of issues? We are using the standard `CLLocationManager` setup for `iBeacon` region monitoring with always access for the location manager. I am going crazy over this issue!

Comment: I have the same issue when exiting from my car when bluetooth is connected... :(

Comment: I'm also seeing my iBeacon come in and out of range repeatedly whilst using the BT for calls in my car. 

Apple reportedly fixed a bunch of BT issues in 10.3, but I'm still having a bad time of it. Anyone managed to figure this out?

Comment: They reportedly have fixed some of the issues, but this problem was not one of them. But I know there are developers working on it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with iBeacons in iOS 10, detecting the iBeacons works but they get a -1 for proximity and accuracy most of the time.

Issue seems to occur both in Swift and in Objective-C. The iPad Air, iPhone 6 and iPod Touch seem to all have this problem in my case (some weeks ago we managed to do a demo with the same code and it worked fine under iOS 9), so we assume it is iOS 10 (GM) related.

It might be also related to the beacons advertising with a speed that is not around 200 ms.

Comment: Thats the conclusion I have made so far as well. Really sucks!